# React Router Redirect not working in Private Route

Tags: reactjs, redirect, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I have this private route component that is used to render a component only is the user is logged in, else it should redirect to the login page.

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
    <Route {...rest} render={props => (
            authToken()
            ? <Component {...props} />
            : <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login', state: { from: props.location } }} />
    )} />
)

export default withRouter(PrivateRoute);
```

and this is my main app:

```
            <BrowserRouter>
                <div className="wrapper">
                    <Switch>
                        <Route path="/login" component={LoginPage} />
                        <> 
                        <div className="dashboard">
                            <SideBar />
                            {permittedEvents &&
                                <div className="content-area">
                                    <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={Dashboard} />
                                    <PrivateRoute exact path="/calendar" component={Calendar} />
                                </div>
                            }
                        </div>
                        </>
                    </Switch>
                </div>
            </BrowserRouter>
```

for some reason the redirect is being ignored completely and when the user is not logged in, the Sidebar gets rendered but nor the content or the login page get rendered.

I have tried returning only the redirect in te Private route to force te redirect and check whether it was something wit my authentication. But the redirect doesn't seem to be working no matter where its included.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need Route

```
class PrivateRoute extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        const { component: Component, ...rest } = this.props;

        const redirectPath = (<Redirect to={{
            pathname: "/login",
            state: {
                from: this.props.location.pathname
            }
        }}/>);

   if (!ok) {
                return redirectPath;
            }
        return <Component {...this.props} />;
    }
};

export default  withRouter(PrivateRoute);
```

Comment: but route was passing props now it just says props is not defined

Comment: and what about the props.location in the redirect?

Comment: I changed the answer. I use class form.